# Error during Data Source initialization error: password authentication failed for user "root" when start with pm2

Tags: node.js, postgresql, ubuntu, typeorm

I'm deploying Nodejs application to Droplet of Digitalocean.When I start it normal(npm start), it work perfectly.But when i start with pm2 , i get this error in pm2 logs.

```
Error during Data Source initialization error: password authentication failed for user "root"
```

this is script in my package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "server": "nodemon dist/index.js",
    "typeorm": "node --require ts-node/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js -d ./dist/data-source.js",
    "build": "rm -rf dist && tsc",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node dist/index.js"
  },
```

I dont use root as owner rule when create database on Droplet, but i dont know why it happen, how can i fix it?

Comment: Have you tried doing it with `sudo`?

Comment: can you explain it more clearly?